# How to install clonezilla on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, installation, clonezilla

I installed latest Ubuntu on a flash drive. Was ready to install clonezilla with `apt-get install clonezilla` but that's not the way to do it?

I prefer a physical install to a live one because I then have a chance to load specialized ntfs drivers for instance, should there be a need.

How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clonezilla doesn't seem to be in the standard Ubuntu repos.  I looked on their mailinglist and it looks like they have setup a third party repo which will allow you to install it using apt-get.

There's a nice guide on the link below, showing how to add this third party repo to your system, once you've done that you should be to `apt-get install clonezilla`

http://packratstudios.com/index.php/2008/04/20/how-to-setup-clonezilla-on-linux-ubuntu-quick-start-guide

Comment: Thank you! The post is from 2008. I wonder if it applies to the newest version of Ubuntu as well ...

Comment: Yes it should work the same way, just make sure on the first line you add to the sources.list file that you specify your version of Ubuntu, so if you're not using hardy, replace the word "hardy" with karmic, jaunty, intrEpid, etc

deb http://free.nchc.org.tw/ubuntu hardy main restricted universe multiverse

Answer (score 2):

I found an article which I always follow, it is actually a walk-through so it is very easy. It even shows you how to create shortcuts on the server's desktop to start the server already configured for multicasting, so you do not have to reconfigure the server every time. Here is the link:

http://geekyprojects.com/cloning/setup-a-clonezilla-server-on-ubuntu/

Good Luck!